# Is it possible to query for a range of hashes of a hashed indexed key in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-query, querying

I have a hashed based sharding enabled for a key "userId" in a mongodb collection. Is it possible to get all documents whose hashed values of "userId" are between, let's say, "abcd" and "cdef"?

Thanks!

Comment: What, do you mean to get the internal hash value back in the result?

Comment: Not necessarily (but would be curious to know how to do it as well). What I'm interested in is the following: assume I have a range of MD5 hashsums: A to B. I want to get all documents in my collection whose hashed value of the sharding key belongs to this range

Comment: that is if document A is hashed to hash 1, B to 2, C to 4 and I have a range [0,3], I want to get documents A and B

Answer (score 0):

One way that I found is to use the following query:

```
db.mycollection.find({
"$and": [
  {_id: {"$gt": -5012941854059245285}}, 
  {_id : {"$lt": -4712634714892678072}}
]}).hint({_id: "hashed"})
```

where the long numbers are hashed values of _id.
It works for me, but is it the best way of doing so? Can I be sure that it will work with the upcoming releases of mongodb?

Comment: You don't need the $and and you probably don't need the hint there but yeah that looks right, you can just do `db.mycollection.find({_id:{$gt:(),$lt:()}})`

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I don't need an "$and". But without the "$hint" I get no results. I suspect that the default index on _id kicks in. Actually, explain() confirms the hypothesis. I'm wondering whether using hint() is not a "hacky" solution and will be portable and working for the upcoming releases

Comment: Ah yes the default index could be taking over, strange I wonder if there should be a JIRA for that. Hint will always be supported but it makes your life as a dev harder when you have to come back and modify these queries, if you can deal with that then it is fine

Comment: I actually would prefer a solution without hint() since I'm concerned that the query optimizer may not respect this hint in the future...

Comment: This solution uses unsupported behavior and breaks with MongoDB 2.6. See the following for guidance on how to construct: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14557