# Bug for collections that are sharded over a hashed key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

When querying for large amounts of data in sharded collections we benefited a lot from querying the shards in parallel.
The following problem does only occur in collections that are sharded over a hashed key.

In Mongo 2.4 it was possible to query with hash borders in order to get all data of one chunk.

We used the query from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726236/is-it-possible-to-query-for-a-range-of-hashes-of-a-hashed-indexed-key-in-mongodb).
It is a range query with hash values as borders:

```
db.collection.find(
{ "_id" : { "$gte" : -9219144072535768301, 
             "$lt" : -9214747938866076750}
}).hint({ "_id" : "hashed"})
```

The same query also works in 2.6 but takes a long time.

The explain() shows that it is using the index but scanned objects is way to high.

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_hashed",
```

Furthermore the borders are wrong.

```
"indexBounds" : {
                "_id" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
```

Was there some big change from 2.4 t0 2.6 which breaks this query?
Even if the borders are interpreted as non-hash values, why does it take so long?

Is there some other way to get all documents of one chunk or hash index range?

Also the [mongo internal hadoop connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) has this problem with sharded collections.

Thanks!

Comment: The MongoDB query engine was rewritten for 2.6 and there were a few regressions post release that are being addressed. What version of 2.6 are your running? If not 2.6.3 I would suggest upgrading to see whether you get the same behavior.

Comment: the mongo version is 2.6.1

Comment: I checked the release notes between 2.6.1 and 3. There is no issue with sharded hashed collections. It is improbable but I will also check the newest mongo.

Comment: It happens also in the newest MongoDB version (2.6.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query above working in 2.4 was not supported behavior. See [SERVER-14557](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14557) with a similar complaint and an explanation of how to properly perform this query. Reformatted for proper behavior, your query becomes:

```
db.collection.find().min({ _id : -9219144072535768301}).max({ _id : -9214747938866076750}).hint({_id : "hashed"})
```

As reported in the SERVER ticket, there is an additional bug ([SERVER-14400](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14400)) that prevents this query from being targeted towards a single shard. At this point in time there are no plans to address in 2.6. This should however prevent the table scan you are seeing under 2.6 and allow for more efficient retrieval.